# CSS - How do I move a button up to be side-by-side?

Tags: css

I just want to move the Cancel Filter button up to the right of the Filter button. This is MVC / Index.cshtml file. I'm using Bootstrap too. I'm using Chrome.

I did an inspect on the 2nd form and manually set the CSS as display: inline-block and it does not move up. I tried a few things with no luck.

```
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Movies", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <p>
            Genre: @Html.DropDownList("movieGenre", "All")
            Title: @Html.TextBox("searchStringEntered")
            <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
        </p>
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Movies", FormMethod.Get))
    {
       <p>
           <input type="submit" value="Cancel Filter" />
       </p>
    }
</p>
```

Here's the screen shot.

[image]

Per discussions below, I created a rule in my Site.css file for the form:

```
.side-by-side {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

In the inspector, I can manually add it to both form tags and it works, but when  I run the page, my custom Site.css file is not being shown. So the rule is not getting to the browser. However, my custom Site.css file shows for other rules elsewhere. **So I don't understand why it is not being picked up by the browser.**

Here is a screenshot of me having manually adding to both form tags - the display: inline-block - and it works. It moved the Cancel Filter button up. The screen shot also shows the new CSS class I added to the tag.

[image]

Here is a screen shot where it picks up my Site.css file and applies a CSS rule. So I know it recognizes it.

[image]

Comment: `p` is a block element by default. If you want to get two of those next to each other, then you need to make them both inline-block.

Comment: You cannot have paragraphs within paragraphs; your markup will break and the browser will close the parent paragraph in odd, unpredictable ways - start there and please provide the rest of the code (the CSS you tried).

Comment: Can't you move the cancel button to the <p> element with the other filter elements?

Comment: @Jayx paragraphs are auto-closing so it doesn't really matter – nevertheless it is bad form/not pretty… :)

Comment: @tobiv I can't because if I do, the URL query string  that I need at cancel click is not being properly specified so it does not perform. So that is why I separated it out into it's own form and I get the cancel behavior I want.

Comment: @Jayx If I remove the p tags surrounding the 3 elements, I get the squiggly red lines and when I run it, I get a compile error whereby it expects a }. Note: This markup is not mine. It is a tutorial that I am doing.

Comment: And if you replace the paragraphs with spans? They are inline by default.

Comment: @tobiv Yes, but it will close the parent before the first nested paragraph, so any hooks on the parent will only apply to the parent - either way ... avoid bugs, keep it tidy.

Comment: @Jayx I replaced the paragraphs with spans and yet no change. As I mentioned,  adding the rule manually works. So I added the class to the form tag as well as my Site.css file. But the file is not being recognized by the Browser as I inspect the buttons,. So I don't understand why that is so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like so:

```
<style> .side-by-side { display: inline-block; } </style>
<p class="side-by-side"> Filter </p>
<p class="side-by-side"> Cancel </p>
```

Because your p blocks that you want side by side are already inside another element this should work.

Comment: I did as suggested - but added it to my CSS file but the file is not being recognized when I run the page. –

Answer (score 0):

remove the p inside the forms since I see no reason to keep them and use

display: inline-block;

for both your forms.

Comment: In inspect, I manually added the display: inline-block; to both form tags and it works. However in my custom .css file, I added form {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
and the file is not recognized when I run the page.

Comment: it looks OK to me. I hate !important, but should do the work. check your CSS file in inspector to see if your rules get to the browser.

Comment: In the inspector, I can manually add it to the form tag and it works, but when  I run the page, my custom CSS file is not being shown. So the rule is not getting to the browser. However, my custom CSS file shows for other rules elsewhere. So I don't understand why it is not being picked up here.